# .dll.refresh auto-updates references. Is there any way to auto-update other kinds of files?

Tags: .net, build, refresh

Pretty straight-forward question.

.dll.refresh auto-updates references.
Is there any way to auto-update other kinds of files?

For example I have a Excel Workbook Project in C#, and I want it to publish and send the xlsx result file to use in another project.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!